# Simple matrix inequality coming from weak duality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

The weak duality property on an optimization problem tells me that for any invertible matrix $A$ and vector $b\in Im(A)$ :
$$
\|b\|^2\le \|A^\intercal b\| \|A^{-1}b\| 
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Frobenius norm.

I checked that this inequality is valid numerically but I don't see the simple argument to show it properly. I get expression depending on the condition number of $A$.

Comment: By the way, $A\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ invertible implies that $Im(A)=\Bbb R^n$ so $b\notin Im(A)$ makes no sense. But as you can see from my answer, if $A$ is invertible, then the inequality holds for any $b\in\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\langle . , . \rangle$ be the usual inner product so that $\|x\|^2 = \langle x,x\rangle$. Then we have
$$\|b\|^2 = \langle b,b\rangle = \langle AA^{-1}b,b\rangle = \langle A^{-1}b,A^\top b\rangle$$
and by Cauchy-Schwarz, we get
$$\|b\|^2 = \langle A^{-1}b,A^\top b\rangle\leq \|A^{-1}b\|\|A^{\top}b\|,$$
which is the desired inequality.